# JavaScript "If" - Why does it not fail?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm implementing mocha tests in nodejs app application and once again I made a mistake.

Instead of writing `it('should ...' , function(done){}); I wrote if('should ...`

```
if ('should implment rest style "destroy" method', function(done){
        request(app)
            .del('/restLike/41')
            .expect(200, '<h1>Rest Like Destroy: 41</h1>')
            .end(done);
    });
```

Stupid mistake, if instead of it. But why does it not fail, why nodes v8 compiles it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's valid JavaScript!

It is an `if` statement whose condition is an expression with the comma operator and whose body is the empty statement (`;`).

The comma operator is defined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator).  The left-hand operand of the comma operator here is a string, and the right-hand operand is a function expression.  The result of the comma-operator expression (which is the function expression) happens to be truthy and the empty body is executed but does nothing.

It may look strange, but it parses -- and executes -- just fine.

Comment: So what is the result of this comma operator? I'm guesing 'true'.

Comment: @xaoonipu - It's a "truthy" value -- the function object.

Comment: Yes function objects are truthy.  Added to the answer.

Comment: Grate answer - thank you. I will now have next JavaScript killer question for interviews ;)